# Need to auto-populate a list column with a sequential number in 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We've come up with our equation to generate job numbers that would show, as example for now, ROV-141 but we want leading zeros between the year and new number, i.e. ROV-1400001 or ROV-1403099. we always want 5 digits after the year & thus that number could be 00001 and all the way up to 09999. how do we modify end of following equation to allow for leading zeros in Sharepoint 2013? no coding please - we don't have a programmer on staff yet, nor do i have access. the equation below works to extent, but not to where we want it to be.

=Brand&"-"&TEXT(Created,"yy")&MAX(ID)

Answer (score 0):

This should add leading zeros:

```
=Brand&"-"&TEXT(Created,"yy")&TEXT(ID,"00000")
```